# What cutlery would rotifer monsters use?

Tags: fantasy-races, food, urban-fantasy, tools

The rotifer monsters are monstrous rotifers with a roughly human level of intellect. They are roughly 7 metres in length and 2 metres in diameter. They possess the power to manipulate gravity, allowing them to leviate and to draw small objects (less than 15 kilograms) towards their mouth: This takes minimal energy. They have humanoid arms, which are around 2 metres in length. Their throat cannot widen beyond 70 centimeters in diameter, and they lack chewing jaws in their mouth

Their natual diet consists of various materials, including solidified sewage, dead vegetable matter, and ocassionally some old meat. They often hold banquets, in which more elaborate foodstuffs are served. These foods include soups, baked goods, sausages, and jellies made from the materials mentioned above: These materials are also served in their raw forms. The elaborate foodstuffs are generally made to be quite large in size and weight. Cutlery is rarely if ever used outside of banquets

The rotifer monsters dwell in forests and abandoned cities within modern day Eastern Europe, and hence have access to the materials found in these environments. They can create tools, but do not have any infrastructure to produce materials. They rarely interact with humans, but do often encounter human tools in their cities

Given this information, what sort of cutlery would such monsters use?

Comment: "... dwell in forests and abandoned cities within Eastern Europe..." in what era?  The available materials will vary enormously from antiquity to the 21st Century or beyond.  Apart from that, it depends on their choices.  Compare the use of chopsticks in east Asian cultures to forks in Europe - same species, different choices.  Given that the creatures have both telekinesis and arms, it is hard to see how there can be a "best" answer to this question, especially as any answer needs to be a list of utensils to cover foodstuffs that are solid, liquid and in-between.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 the limiting factor here is, that they **can't chew**

Comment: @Trish which means that they may use knives to cut larger food into digestible pieces, or run it over a grater, or use a sharp grid that they push food through with telekinesis, or...  There are many possible solutions to the problem, any of which might fit the definition of "banquet table manners for weird monster" and no objective way to judge between them.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 They don't have telekinesis, just gravity manipulation to draw in food

Comment: @IchthysKing that's no better than saying "_they don't move things about by 'magic', they move things about by <magic>_". Maybe your question currently lacks some important detail?

Comment: "They possess the power to manipulate gravity, allowing them to leviate and to draw small objects (less than 15 kilograms) towards their mouth." What's the cost? If it's nearly effortless, it will impact their behaviour very differently than if manipulating gravity is very tiresome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Daily Cooking

#### Meat mincers / meat grinder

They lack jaws that can chew their food, so they require their food to be pre-chewed to ensure the best digestion - which requires food to be as evenly mushed as possible. For this effect, the rotifer monster will use a meat grinder, turning their food into a fine paste.

They have a clear preference for mechanical meat mincers with large openings, which allows them to process larger chunks, though they also have been seen using small food processors and blenders if available.

#### Mortar and pestle, coffee mills, and wheat mills

When no food processor, meat grinder or similar is available, they also have been seen using mortar and pestle as well as coffee and wheat mills to achieve the fine paste they savor. Among these machines, the rule seems to be the larger the better, so Japanese mortars for making mochi are quite preferred over normal kitchen ones and the rotifer monster that has acquired a medieval windmill intact is almost a king because they can process whole feasts into their food paste while everybody is watching and filling their gullets.

#### Chopper

Chopper knives, especially with two grips and of very curvy design will have to do where food can't be put through other ways to paste them. The bent deign of the knife allows them to easily turn the food into tiny pieces or nigh-paste by just altering the pressure from side to side.

### Banquet Cutlery

#### Soup Ladles & Spoons

Some rotifer monsters will have mastered the art of paste-cooking by taking the food material and cooking it into a nutrious paste, very akin to manufacturing of [meat extract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat_extract). Others prepare the food the more traditional way, chopping, grinding or cooking it into a fine paste or liquid soup.

As all the foods but baked goods as a result are quite liquid, they need a bowlish tool. Baked goods are consumed by tossing them into the soups, turning them soggy fillings to the soups. In either case soup and paste will be consumed with what to us appears like a soup ladle or oversized spoon, due to the size of the mouth.

In daily life, the food paste is levitated directly into the mouth, or drunken from the bowls.